# Is there a good Java library for generation of order preserving O(1) hash codes, based on a set of attributes and a comparator?

Tags: java, hash, hashcode

Given set of attributes and a comparator I'd like to generate an order preserving hash code that provides O(1) access. Is there a Java library for this sort of thing or would I have to design the hash function myself?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
java.util.LinkedHashMap()
```

Comment: LinkedHashMap doesn't provide for custom ordering, just insertion order or least-recently-accessed order.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single collection that will do this. Depending on the detail requirements there are several options to chose from.

For simplicity, I would just use a HashMap for lookups and when I need the sorted data, I'd make a copy of the values and sort it:

```
 List<?> sorted = new ArrayList<?>(hashMap.values());
 Collections.sort(sorted, Comparator<?>);
```

This suffices for most real world use cases.

You could also write your own super-container that internally holds the elements in *two* collections, one HashMap and maybe a TreeSet. You can then easily provide access methods that make use of the collection better for the purpose of the method. Just make sure you make additions and removals affect both the contained collections.